# iOS: How to add/insert specific cell with identifier into UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, insert, tableview, cells

I have grouped static cells in a UITableView. Now I'd like to add or delete (what is easier?) one specific cell, which I've already created in my storyboard. It depends on one NSString: If my string == YES, the cell should be displayed, else it shouldn't.

already tried `tableView:insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

Comment: What do you mean by you have created that one cell in storyboard? Has it already been added statically in the UITableView?

Comment: right. it's already existing.

Comment: like the cell in the iphone settings if you activate flightmode (hide/unhide).

Comment: Sorry for the absence. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method is part of the UITableViewDelegate protocol and will be called when the table view is about to draw a cell for a particular row. This provides a UITableViewCell for you to work with.

To identify which cell you need to hide, you can add a tag to the UITableViewCell in the storyboard. This is easier because you are adding static cells.

Then you can just do:

```
if ([cell tag] == someInteger) {
    cell.hidden = YES;
}
```

You can wrap this in a condition based on the value of your string that you have mentioned.

[I have added some example code on Github to illustrate this.](https://github.com/n9986/SelectiveTableViewCells)

Comment: I found the solution: your code works, but there is space the remove and more. I  used heightForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection and it works fine :) so I'll give you the points.