# How do I add a specific tableview cell into a tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, insert

I have looked through stackoverflow and there are some questions that seem to brush the sides of this but none that actually answer it.

The closest I have found is this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562197/ios-how-to-add-insert-specific-cell-with-identifier-into-uitableview/12598072#12598072) but this isn't what I am after.

I have a tableview which is filled with tableview cells (lets call them A cells). When I click one of these cells I want to insert another custom tableview cell below it (B cells).

The other answers I have had always involved hiding and revealing cells but I want to be able to click multiple times to keep adding more of these custom cells.

This is what I am currently working with:

```
-(id) initWithGuestNumber: (NSInteger *) numberOfPeople {
    self = [super initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
    if (self) {

        numberOfGuests = * numberOfPeople;
        guestArray = [NSMutableArray new];

        for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= numberOfGuests; i++) {

            BGuest * guest = [BGuest alloc];
            NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray new];

            // Set up guest object
            guest.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Person %li", (long)i];
            guest.mealArray = array;
            guest.priceArray = array;
            guest.cost = 0;

            [guestArray addObject:guest];
        }
    }
     return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up custom tableview cells
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BHeaderCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BContentCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView_
{
    // Want a section for each guest
    return guestArray.count;
} 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    BGuest * guest = guestArray[section];
    // Want a row in the section for each meal added to each guest - by clicking the row
    return guest.mealArray.count + 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BHeaderCell * headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];
    BContentCell * contentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];

    // Setting the delegate programatically to set the textfield


    BGuest * guest = guestArray[indexPath.section];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        headerCell.guestNameTextField.delegate = headerCell;
        headerCell.guestNameTextField.placeholder = guest.name;
        headerCell.guestMealPriceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%.2f", guest.cost];
}
    else {

        contentCell.mealNameTextField.delegate = contentCell;
        contentCell.mealCostTextField.delegate = contentCell;

        contentCell.mealNameTextField.text = @"Meal Name";
        contentCell.mealCostTextField.text = @"Meal Cost";
    }

    return headerCell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BGuest * guest = guestArray[indexPath.section];

    NSString * first = @"first";
    [guest.mealArray addObject:first];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

So currently when I click a row a new row is added below but it is the same custom cell as the row clicked (clicking an A cell adds another A cell underneath).

What I want is to insert a new custom cell underneath when the row is clicked (click an A cell and a B cell is inserted underneath).

Is there any way to do this using insertrowatindexpath or is there a better/different way?

Thanks for and help you guys/girls can give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I clicked post question it suddenly popped out in front of me.

Currently in my code I was always returning the headerCell (A cell)

I switched round the code slightly in the cellForRowAtIndex and it started working:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Setting the delegate programatically to set the textfield


    BGuest * guest = guestArray[indexPath.section];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        BHeaderCell * headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];

        headerCell.guestNameTextField.delegate = headerCell;

        headerCell.guestNameTextField.placeholder = guest.name;

        headerCell.guestMealPriceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%.2f", guest.cost];

        return headerCell;
    }
    else {

        BContentCell * contentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];

        //contentCell.mealNameTextField.delegate = contentCell;
        //contentCell.mealCostTextField.delegate = contentCell;

        contentCell.mealNameTextField.text = @"Yeah";
        contentCell.mealCostTextField.text = @"£1.50";

        return contentCell;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will save people the time it took me to spot in the future